# Cannot move map in webview

Tags: android, android-fragments, webview, leaflet

One activity (MainActivity) calls a fragment(MainPage). The fragment is designed to open a local asset webview file, Map.html. It works as intended, with the exception that the map cannot be moved by fingertip. This function is available when the Map.html is opened a broswer. However, the zoom in zoom out tap button in the top left does work.

Is something overlaying the webview such that it can be seen but not swiped?

[image: Map Screenshot]

The initial AppCompatActivity (to support ActionBar) is given by MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    //list of private declarations

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // a lot of other stuff relating to navigation drawer

    // calls MainPage Fragment
    android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment = new MainPage();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
                        .addToBackStack("tag")
                        .commit();
    }
}
```

where the xml for this is given as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/content_frame">
    </WebView>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:background="#111">
        </ListView>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Eventually calls MainPage, given as:

```
public class MainPage extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment implements GeolocationPermissions.Callback {

    public MainPage() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
        WebView webview = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webview.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
        GeoClient geo = new GeoClient();
        webview.setWebChromeClient(geo);
        String origin = "";
        geo.onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(origin, this);
        webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/Map.html");
        return rootView;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to set an onclicklistener. For Google Maps, this is how I did it. Its probably similar.

Add the implements, @override function, and set the onclick listener. I'm not sure if this will work since you are using HTML at some point.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements View.OnClickListener,
        GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener {
```

Then when you initiate it set the onmap click listener.

```
    gMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);// add the listener for click on gmap object
```

Finally, add this @override:

```
@Override
public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
//What code if any happens when user clicks on map
}
```