# Implemented OnTouchListener, but ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN constantly being output

Tags: android, layout, webview, ontouchlistener, ontouch

I've implemented OnTouchListener() as follows

```
webView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch(event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                Log.e("ACTION","ACTION_MOVE");
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

However, when I touch the webView, the output is as follows

```
D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
E/ACTION: ACTION_MOVE
E/ACTION: ACTION_MOVE
D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
E/ACTION: ACTION_MOVE
E/ACTION: ACTION_MOVE
D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
E/ACTION: ACTION_MOVE
E/ACTION: ACTION_MOVE
E/ACTION: ACTION_MOVE
E/ACTION: ACTION_MOVE
E/ACTION: ACTION_MOVE
E/ACTION: ACTION_MOVE
```

The multiple log outputs is as a result of me dragging my finger down the screen. However, no matter what direction the touch is made, ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN is output and the webView view does not move. Why does ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN keep repeating?

Related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42216005/cannot-move-map-in-webview/42216671#42216671) for layouts. Other answers from SO including every single one of [these](https://www.google.ca/search?q=ViewPostImeInputStage%20ACTION_DOWN%20site:stackoverflow.com&safe=off&rlz=1C5CHFA_enCA721CA721&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiLrsyL4pDSAhXG7YMKHb1GDx8QrQIIJygEMAA&biw=1263&bih=648) don't work

Comment: `Why does ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN keep repeating?` When has it been repeated? I see only one ACTION_DOWN in your logs.

Comment: That's a parsed section of the log. The total log has "D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN" in repeat